# Permission denied (publickey) sudo ssh -i <pem file> ubuntu@ip?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

I’m connecting a ec-2 instance with my ubuntu terminal, and and I am still facing a problem Permission denied (publickey). When i run following command `sudo ssh -i Desktop/iris.pem ubuntu@13.127.228.214`?”

```
iris@iris:~$ sudo ssh -i Desktop/iris.pem ubuntu@13.127.228.214
[sudo] password for iris:
```

I expect instance connection message but it stuck in `Permission denied (publickey).`

Help Me out

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` in the command?

Comment: Do you have the correct ssh key added to your ssh daemon ?

Answer (score 0):

When you download your pem file form **AWS** it will be public permissions. You have to modify the permissions to 400 for your pem file and try connecting.

```
$ chmod 400 Desktop/iris.pem
$ ssh -i Desktop/iris.pem ubuntu@13.127.228.214
```

I hope, it help you to connect. If not let me know.

Comment: No its not working, i already provide  400 permission to `pem key` but still happens this any other reference

Comment: don't use `sudo`